# No errors, but no success in jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm doing an ajax call to my controller, but the alert in my success isn't displaying and I'm not getting errors in console. I don't know how to proceed now.

**Controller - rate**

```
function graph($userid, $courseid){

    $i_am_admin = $this->logged_in->logged_as_admin();
    if($this->session->userdata('id') == $userid || $i_am_admin ){
        $this->load->model('rate_model');
        $graph_data = array();

        if($query = $this->rate_model->graphRate($userid, $courseid)){
            $data['rate']  = $query;
        }
        $data['graph_json'] = json_encode($query);

        $data['content'] = 'rate_graph_view';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
        return json_encode($query);
    }
}
```

**Script.js**

```
$('.profileimg').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url, // url = http://localhost/herexamen/project/rate/graph/6/4
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
            alert(output_string);
            alert("yes");
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call
});
```

Comment: is the graph() function actully called?

Comment: I thought it is called by the URL?

Comment: That is correct, codeigniter will call the `graph` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You aren't checking if the ajax call failed

The appended code isn't the solution, by any means, but can shed light on your problems.  Notice I added the `error` section to the ajax request.

What is the result of this call?

```
$('.profileimg').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
        type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_string){
                    alert(output_string);
                    alert("yes");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            }
    }); // End of ajax call
});
```

Comment: That means that the data you are returning isn't in the `json` format.
If you want, try and remove `dataType: 'json'`, and see what the output_string is.

Comment: How can that be? The last line in my controller is an encoded json query

Comment: Well, if you remove `dataType`, what does it return?

Comment: It returns my complete HTML page and success function is being executed, both alerts show up

Comment: There's your problem!  It's trying to convert your HTML to json.  You just need to print the result of the `json_encode`.  Create a view that just output's the result of the json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35108/discussion-between-mxx-and-kirk-backus)

Comment: I haven't downvoted but down voters needs to place the comment but i thinks its the criticism

Comment: Yes, but only outputting the json object, will just give me the json, what about my other content on the html page? And how am I able to use my json object? Like output_string.KeyName?

Answer (score 0):

While making `ajax` calls you are supposed to  echo the content or response to send and you are using return try this

```
echo json_encode($query);
```

Why view is loaded when you are making json and only

```
function graph($userid, $courseid){

        $i_am_admin = $this->logged_in->logged_as_admin();

        if($this->session->userdata('id') == $userid || $i_am_admin ){
            $this->load->model('rate_model');
            $graph_data = array();

        if($query = $this->rate_model->graphRate($userid, $courseid)){
            $data['rate']  = $query;
        }
        $data['graph_json'] = json_encode($query);

        $data['content'] = 'rate_graph_view';
       $data['viewloaded']= $this->load->view('templates/template', $data,true);
        echo json_encode($data);
        die();
    }
}
```

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending
>   it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data
>   in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned

[**CI Views**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Comment: I thought you can't do an echo in the controller by the MVC principle?

Comment: This isn't really the case.  He is using `codeigniter`, and is calling a view.  Either way, the alert would show.

Comment: I'm calling the view because that is what I want to show, and with the json data I'll be manipulating that.

Comment: But your controller will handle the requests and for ajax the better way is use as above rather going to call view and echoing your json

Comment: First: I think you can't echo in your controller - that is just MVC. Second: I tried your code like that, but that just outputs the json object on an empty page no succes alert.

Comment: Then wrap all the information in one variable and then encode into json  in your case you have html also and json also while in ajax call you have defined the response will be in json `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @down voters better to mention comment whats wrong in the answer